# Latitude Longitude coordinates are being padded with extra digits in python float

Tags: python, pandas, floating

I have data in csv file that I am reading using pandas. There are latitude, longitude coordinates, some have higher precision than others.
for ex, -117.8982898932 or -100.3456. The ones that have a lower precision, python is padding it with 0000001 so it becomes -100.34560000001.
I want to pad the lower precision number with zeroes. But how do I know how many zeroes to add as each number has different precision?

This is important because once I read in the data (which is terabytes, there are numbers, strings, datetime, latitude, longitude, etc), I am doing preprocessing and then I want to make sure I have read in the correct data so I am comparing with the original csv file.

So if original file has -100.3456 and python stores is as -100.34560000001, and when I compare, its a problem. I have not checked all numbers but it will be a problem if its padding with digits other than zero.

Comment: what is the dtype: `float32` or `float64`? what does the raw data look like in a text editor not excel?

Comment: `"{my_num:0.6f}".format(my_num=100.3456)` will give you a string with your desired padding ... the weird extra bit is due to the inherent weirdness of storing floating point numbers in binary (ie its a problem with floats in all languages)

Comment: Please provide a sample dataset so I can have a look inside it.

Comment: Here is sample dataset 
31.7614929,-71.0637227,2187.0, United States,2016-05-11 02:46:21 UTC

The numbers are stored as float64. Should latitude and longitude be stored as a different datatype?  
@JoranB

Comment: @joranbeasley, I agree with you. But doesn't adding extra bits change internal calculations? 0.00000001 may matter in some cases.